# jQuery alternatives to jquery.validate.js for form validation

Tags: jquery, forms

I am currently using jQuery validate.js, I am looking for something more advanced and visually more presentable

I am looking for some other jQuery based form validators to check and validate 
 1. numbers 
 2. IP addresses
 3. date,
 4. time ,
 5. text characters etc or    anything

Can anyone recommend some jQuery based form validations with ease of use, but also has a rich interface and easy to customize  and lot of examples to refer to if needed?

Comment: What's wrong with this one? (please specify in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check dis out....

[10 useful form validators](http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/)

[jquery auto validate](http://phrogz.net/tmp/FormAutoValidate/formautovalidate_docs.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) may be one to try. The answer above is a little dated.