# JQuery Validation - Alternatives

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Does anyone know of any other good JQuery-compatible validation libraries besides [JQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)?

I've been having a lot of difficultly with it so I want to see if there is anything better before I go and write something myself.

EDIT:

The "duplicate" question is 6 months old (out-of-date) and references only a single alternative. I'd like to try and get more answers, if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery alternatives to jquery.validate.js for form validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896778/jquery-alternatives-to-jquery-validate-js-for-form-validation)

Comment: @MohammadAdil That's the same thing as what I reference in my question.

Comment: @user125697 That question only had a single actual library in the answer. Doesn't fit what I'm looking for unfortunately.

Comment: see this [list of plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-form-validation-plugins/)

Answer (score 4):

[Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) is a JavaScript library, that can work with both jQuery or Zepto, designed to validate forms easily. It is built with UX concerns in mind and tries to simplify details for the user.

Is this what you're looking for?